# How to avoid special characters in csv export?

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my  http://nridubai.com Website,there are one feature - export all data in csv format.And this is only available to admin.

But In my databse there are some companies contains non english characters like **Äž** .

When i export it into csv format,these characters replaces with strange characters.But when i try open that csv file with notepad,it showing proper.

Please  help me sort out the problem
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for your solution,Its working for me.Sorry but how to accept the correct answer? and sorry again for stupid question.

Comment: Nah its a good question, when I first started using the site I didn't notice the holo checkbox next to each answer either! Good luck!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem you can resolve in CSV. Special chars will be included, but when you open that CSV in notepad or excel, those special chars are converted into the correct chars.

Try using UTF8 encoding while streaming out the CSV.